# Invoke function of an object in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an generic function which will take the following params :
object of an JavaScript class(type object), method name(type string) and passing param (type object) . somewhat like below I have written my function named InvokeFunction :

```
function InvokeFunction(objPerson , eventName, objParam)
{
 // now here I want to invoke an function(eventName) which is present in  objPerson(an javascript class) and also pass an objParam as it is an parametrized function
}
```

**Need to Do this :**

As I want an one common place where I will pass just an object and event name and an parameter need of that function.

It will be handled inside try catch block so if the event name passed is not present in the object I will handle the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
objPerson[eventName](objParam);
```

In JavaScript, "methods" are just functions attached to properties and called by looking up the property and calling the function in the same expression.

And in JavaScript, you can refer to a property in two ways: Using dot notation and a literal name:

```
obj.foo();
```

or using bracketed notation and a string:

```
obj["foo"]();
```

The string can be the result of any expression, so it can be a string literal, a variable reference, the result of a calcuation, whatever.